# jQuery Mobile triggers events multiple times

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mobile, alert

If you will click 1-3, then you will be redirected to another site which is in its own file. If you will click 4-6 then go back and click on Ahoj button you will se string "ahoj" 2 times which is not what i want. I want to display it only one time. Do you know where is the problem? Thank you for answers.

http://testepi.kvalitne.cz/demicko/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
$("#tlacitko").off('click').click(function(){
      alert("ahojte");
   });
```

Or if .off() not supported, use unbind:

```
$("#tlacitko").unbind('click').click(function(){
      alert("ahojte");
   });
```